# How can I have a powershell module that sets default parameter values for function calls both in and out of the

Tags: powershell

In my powershell module I have a function `DoStuff` that takes parameter `foo`.  When you call   the `Initialize` function I want it to make all invocations of `DoStuff` pass in a default value for `foo` if not specified.

Normally, this is done via `$PSDefaultParameterValues` however I have noticed functions run inside the modules and functions run outside the module (i.e. run from the shell) do not use the same default parameter dictionary.

An example is the following:

```
function Test1 ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$testParam)
{
   $global:PSDefaultParameterValues["Print:output"] = $testParam
}

function Test2 ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$testParam)
{
   $PSDefaultParameterValues["Print:output"] = $testParam
}

function CallPrint
{
   Print
}

function Print([Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][String]$output)
{
    Write-Host $output
}
```

To illustrate my issue I ran the following commands:

> PS C:\Users\ms> Import-Module '.\Documents\Test Powershell Scripts\ModuleTest.psm1'
>
> PS C:\Users\ms>Test1 abc
>
> PS C:\Users\ms> Test2 def
>
> PS C:\Users\ms> CallPrint
>
> def
>
> PS C:\Users\ms> Print
>
> abc

What this shows is that `$PSDefaultParameterValues` is used when calling a function from within the module, but `$global:PSDefaultParameterValues` is used when calling a function from outside the module.

Is there any way to get consistent behavior without setting both of these at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

Since the Global scope and the module scope obviously have their on $PSDefaultParameterValues, you'll have to set both. You can simplify it by setting the global scope first, and then

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues = $Global:PSDefaultParameters.clone()
```

in the module to sync the values.

That being said, setting those values in the global scope sounds like a bad idea with a potential for unintended consequences.